# Fix On Scroll Using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a fixed header underneath it a hero image that has on top of it an anchor menu, I want that when the anchor menu reaches on scroll the header tag it should become fixed, but when the anchor menu scrolls back to its original page position it should become unfixed. I have the neccesary css to make it work but I can't seem to figure out the jquery code I would need to make this work.
This is the code I had until now but this won't work because my header and anchor menu are responsive and scale according to viewport size so the gap between the anchor menu and header keeps changing.

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 687) {
        $(".anchor-menu").addClass("anchor-menu-grey");
      } else {
        $(".anchor-menu").removeClass("anchor-menu-grey");
      }
    });
```